# Attaching a new disk to Azure IAAS VM caused a reboot?

Tags: azure, iaas

I recently attached a new empty data disk to an Azure IAAS VM running Windows Server 2012 datacenter. As soon as the disk was added. Windows rebooted. This surprised me greatly, as I didn't expect added a data disk to cause a reboot. I looked in the event log and didn't see any errors, the event log indicated NT AUTHORTIY\SYSTEM initiated the reboot.

I attached another disk after it came back up, and it behaved as expected, the disk was added without a reboot.

Does anyone know why/what circumstances would cause an operation like that to make the system trigger a reboot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't expected behaviour, and isn't anything I've seen before.

I've added numerous data disks to numerous IaaS VMs on Azure, in both Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 2012 R2, and I've never seen a VM reboot automatically as a result of that action.

Is there any chance you were doing anything else at same time which may have caused the reboot, such as a silent software installation?  Alternatively you might have been particularly unfortunate if it coincided with a scheduled Azure maintenance window (although you would normally see something in the Event Log if that was the case).